# Python: Get key of the outer of two nested dicts based on one of the values in the inner dict in one line

Tags: python

How to get the desired result in python?

Base nested dictionary:

```
dictionary = {"aliceCo": {'name': "Cooper, Alice", 'group': 'finance'},
              "bobDe": {'name': "Decker, Bob", 'group': 'hr'},
              "caecilEl": {'name': "Elton, Caecil", 'group': 'sales'}
              [many similar entrys...]
              }
```

My attempt:

```
def get_result_list(dictionary, search_string):
    return [[key for inner_val in val.values() if search_string in inner_val] for key, val in dictionary.items()]

my_result_list = get_result_list(dictionary, 'sales')
```

My result:

```
my_result_list = [[], [], ['caecilEl'], [], [], ...]
```

Desired result:

```
my_result_list = ['caecilEl']
```

I get that I have double lists from the return line, but I found no way to omit them. Also all the empty lists are not wanted. I could go over the result and fix it in another function, but I wish to do it in the inital function.

**Thanks for any advice or hints on where to look for a solution!**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The linked duplicate should answer your question. You should also read [ask] and note that, since this is *not a discussion forum*, questions [should not include](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions/) language thanking people (unnecessary and a distraction for people who search later), or saying that any help or hints are desired ([not specific enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)).

Comment: Finally, here is [a great resource for list comprehension questions](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty lists are included because of the nested list.

This function would give the desired result.

```
def get_result_list(dictionary, search_string):
    return [key for key, val in dictionary.items() if search_string in val.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it is better to even use a for loop since it is easier to understand and read. I've tried both the solutions:

Using list comprehension:

```
dnames = {"aliceCo": {'name': "Cooper, Alice", 'group': 'finance'},
          "bobDe": {'name': "Decker, Bob", 'group': 'hr'},
          "caecilEl": {'name': "Elton, Caecil", 'group': 'sales'}
          }
ans = [key for key,value in dnames.items() if value['group'] == 'sales']
ans
```

Using 2 for loop:

```
ans = []
for key,value in dnames.items():
    for key1,value1 in value.items():
        if value1 == 'sales':
            ans.append(key)
```

Using 1 for loop:

```
ans = []
for key,value in dnames.items():
     if value['group] == 'sales':
     ans.append(key)
```